# XML error validating appengine-web.xml

Tags: java, xml, google-app-engine

I get this error when I try to deploy to Google AppEngine:

```
com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: XML error validating /Users/matt/Documents/workspace/myapp222/war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml against /Users/matt/Downloads/eclipse 7/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle.1.3.1_1.3.1.v201002101412/appengine-java-sdk-1.3.1/docs/appengine-web.xsd
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.validateXml(Application.java:322)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.<init>(Application.java:87)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.readApplication(Application.java:121)
at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.proxy.AppEngineBridgeImpl.createAppAdmin(AppEngineBridgeImpl.java:204)
at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.proxy.AppEngineBridgeImpl.deploy(AppEngineBridgeImpl.java:265)
at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.deploy.DeployProjectJob.runInWorkspace(DeployProjectJob.java:145)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-pattern-valid: Value '0s' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '\s*(([1-9][0-9]*)([DdHhMm]|[sS]?))(\s+([1-9][0-9]*)([DdHhMm]|[sS]?))*\s*' for type 'expirationType'.
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.processOneAttribute(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.processAttributes(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.StreamValidatorHelper.validate(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.ValidatorImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.validation.Validator.validate(Validator.java:127)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.validateXml(Application.java:319)
... 7 more
```

My appengine-web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
      <application>myapp222</application>
      <version>1</version>

      <!-- Configure serving/caching of GWT files -->
      <static-files>
        <include path="**" />

        <!-- The following line requires App Engine 1.3.2 SDK -->
        <include path="**.nocache.*" expiration="0s" />

        <include path="**.cache.*" expiration="365d" />
        <exclude path="**.gwt.rpc" />
      </static-files>

      <!-- Configure java.util.logging -->
      <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
      </system-properties>

</appengine-web-app>
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-pattern-valid:
Value '0s' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern
'\s*(([1-9][0-9]*)([DdHhMm]|[sS]?))(\s+([1-9][0-9]*)([DdHhMm]|[sS]?))*\s*'
for type 'expirationType'.
```

```
<include path="**.nocache.*" expiration="0s" />
```

`0s` is not valid. You must specify at least `1s`.

Comment: For some reason it was added despite it being an App Engine 1.3.1 project. Removing the line fixed it. Thanks!